# Can we use wild cards for slot values in Rasa Core Stories?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm trying to get a reasonable understanding of how Rasa Core handles stories.
I basically have 3 entities - `occasion`, `relationship` and `gender`

Based on the different values of each of these, I'd like to utter certain templates. However, there are times when say `occasion` is `Christmas`, and no matter what `relationship` or `gender` slots are filled with, I'd still want to use a certain template.

However, the only way I seem to get around this is by entering all permutation values of `relationship` and `gender` for a given value of `occasion` as `Christmas`.

Can I rather use something like this:

`* suggest {"occasion": "Christmas", "relationship": *, "gender" : *}`

I've tried a story line in Rasa with this:

`* suggest {"occasion": "Christmas"}`

However when I put in a query for "Where would you suggest I should take my brother for Christmas", Rasa NLU identifies the slot `occasion` as `Christmas` and `relationship` as `brother`, and my story line is never called, since now `relationship` is set to `brother`.
I wouldn't say its intuitive to permute every possible combination for `relationship` with `occasion` as `Christmas`, rather I'd achieve this programatically through actions then. However, I just thought I'd be able to take the benefit of Rasa stories and understand the concept better.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rasa Core currently does not a functionality for "wildcard" slots.
However, I am not entirely sure whether this is actually needed.

**Case 1:**
You want to utter different templates depending on which slots are filled. In this case you have to provide different stories (with the different combinations) to your training data.

**Case 2:** You don't care whether some slot is filled and want the bot to utter the same template. In this case I suggest to set the slot type of the ignored slots to `unfeaturized` as it is described [here](https://rasa.com/docs/core/slots/). `unfeaturized` will mean that is does not affect the stories whether these slots are set.

Comment: Thanks@Tobias
There are certain cases where I'd need this. For Eg.
Possible slot values for `occasion` can be `funeral`,`marriage`,`birthday`,etc. `relationship` can be `mother`,`friend`,`father`
When user enters query "I need flowers for my friend funeral".Rasa NLU will identify `friend` as the `relationship` entity & `funeral` as the `occasion`.What I essentially need is irrespective of what `relationship` entity value be, if `occasion` is `funeral` Core should utter the same template.I wouldn't want to write down stories for all combination of `funeral` with every `relationship`